# Master atualizou sozinha com o checkout

Tags: git, github

Bom dia pessoal! Eu estava trabalhando em uma branch e quando eu executei o checkout para a master (git checkout master) ela atualizou sem eu fazer o merge. Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
abel@abel-Vostro-3500:~/Documentos/Drapp/front-web$ git checkout master
M       src/app/pages/painel/doctor/new/new.component.html
M       src/app/pages/painel/doctor/new/new.component.ts
M       src/environments/environment.ts
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
abel@abel-Vostro-3500:~/Documentos/Drapp/front-web$
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: O que você queria fazer exatamente?

Comment: Eu estava trabalhando em uma branch  e tinha finalizado o que tinha de fazer nela, porem eu não fiz o commit, eu executei logo o git checkout master porque apartir de master eu iria criar outra feature para fazer outra coisa. aí apareceu isso na master

Comment: Já tentou fazer o `checkout` para a outra branch e realizar o commit? A master não atualizou sozinha, você apenas levou as mudanças para ela...

Comment: Nesse caso teria que fazer o commit antes de mudar para a master ou executar o git stash correto?

Comment: Sim, teria que ter commitado... o que eu recomendo é sempre fazer um checkout para outra branch antes de começar a desenvolver

Comment: Certo!!! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que for fazer o merge em questão commite antes.

```
git commit -m "{o que você fez}"
```

Caso necessite trocar de branch antes de subir no caso para master(boas praticas). Utilize o:

```
git checkout -b feature/{nome-da-sua-feature}
```